# Toggle between .m and .h file in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode9

With Xcode 9 cmd+ctrl+↑ no longer toggles between .m and .h files but jumps to the previous counterpart which results in annoyingly navigating between .m, .h and test cases files. Anyone knows a shortcut just to toggle between interface and implementation files?

Comment: Not only test cases, but swift extensions also.  And then you can no longer return to the .h/.m files.